# How to show a javascript alert without refreshing the page in Yii?

Tags: javascript, yii2, alert

I have the following code to avoid duplicated names of products on my table. But when I accept the alert dialog it sends me to a blank page.

```
/**
 * Creates a new Producto model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Producto();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        if(($productos = ['nombre_producto' => Yii::$app->request->get('nombre_producto')])!=null){
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Produdcto already exists");</script>';
        }else {
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code with form elements?

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have added the

```
return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
]);
```

In the `else` part and the script is in the first `if`.

Also use the `type="text/javascript"` rather than `javascript` only, although browser has that type by default now you can skip that part too and use

```
$script=<<<JS
alert("Produdcto already exists");
JS;
$this->getView()->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY)
```

you should change your function to

```
/**
 * Creates a new Producto model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Producto();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        if(($productos = ['nombre_producto' => Yii::$app->request->get('nombre_producto')])!=null){
                  $script=<<<JS
                  alert("Produdcto already exists");
                  JS;
                  $this->getView()->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY)
        }else {
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
        }
    } 

    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```